# Properly set uniform array in OpenGL shader

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, matrix

I have two uniform arrays

```
uniform mat4 uLightSpaceMatrices[6];
uniform float uDepthSplits[kMaxCascades];
```

Where kMaxCascades is defined as follows

```
const int kMaxCascades = 4;
```

The only way I can set values correctly is by obtaining separate uniform locations for each element in the array:

1. For matrix array

   ```
   template <std::size_t size>
   void setUniformArray(const std::string& uniformName, const std::array<glm::mat4, size>& matrices) {
         for(int i = 0; i < matrices.size(); ++i) {
              glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(mName, (uniformName + "[" + std::to_string(i) + "]").c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(matrices[i]));
         }
   }
   ```
2. For floats array

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < cascades.splits.size(); ++i) {
        std::string name = "uDepthSplits";
        std::string fullName = name + "[" + std::to_string(i) + "]";
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(mName, fullName.c_str()), cascades.splits[i]);
   }
   ```

   Where splits is a `std::vector< float >`

Now, what is not working, but should (as I see it):

1. For matrix array

   Just one call to glUniformMatrix4fv with number of matrices specified

   ```
   template <std::size_t size>
   void setUniformArray(const std::string& uniformName, const std::array<glm::mat4, size>& matrices) {
       glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(mName, uniformName.c_str()), matrices.size(), GL_FALSE, matrices.data());
   }
   ```
2. For floats array

   ```
   glUniform1fv(glGetUniformLocation(mName, "uDepthSplits"), cascades.splits.size(), cascades.splits.data());
   ```

The question is **WHY** does one approach work and another doesn't?

Comment: What does `glGetError` return? And what does `glGetUniformLocation` return?

Comment: Your comment led me to a solution. There is a very stupid bug on my end. The code I posted is actually slightly different from what I'm using in my project. In my project I get all uniform names using glGetProgramiv and glGetActiveUniform at initialization stage, then put all name - location pairs in a map. I get locations from that map when its time to make glUniform... calls. As it turned out glGetActiveUniform gives uDepthSplits[0] as a name of the uniform which leads to absence of uDepthSplits key in the map. glGetUniformLocation works equally well with uDepthSplits and uDepthSplits[0].

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading you by substituting code pieces, but that brought a solution, interestingly enough.